# How can I use external dependencies in inlined web workers in my library without bundling them?

Tags: typescript, webpack, web-worker

I am developing a library that has some heavy computations that needs to run in a worker, and which relies on an external dependency. Since I'm creating a library, I'd like to inline the web worker to avoid having to host it from an external server for my users. I am able to make this work by bundling the external dependency in my library.

However, I'd like to avoid bundling it, as the size of the bundled dependency can be significant. Is there a way to achieve this?

### A minimal example

Here, `luxon` is the external dependency:

`index.ts`:

```
import DateWorker from './datePrinter.worker';

export function printDate() {

  const worker = new DateWorker();
  worker.postMessage('hello');

  worker.onmessage = (response: { data: { answer: string } } ) => {
    console.log("[main] The date is: ", response.data.answer);
  };
}
```

`datePrinter.worker.ts`:

```
import { DateTime } from 'luxon';

const ctx: Worker = self as any;

ctx.onmessage = (event: MessageEvent<string>) => {
  console.log('[worker] Got message', event.data);

  // Imagine there is some long-running job using external libraries happening here

  ctx.postMessage({ answer: DateTime.now().toLocaleString() });
};

export default null as any;
```

`webpack.config.js`:

```
module.exports = {
    mode: 'development',
    entry: { index: './index.ts' },
    resolve: { extensions: ['.ts'] },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.worker\.ts$/,
                loader: 'worker-loader',
                options: {
                    inline: 'no-fallback'
                }
            },
            {
                test: /\.ts$/,
                loader: 'ts-loader'
            }
        ]
    },
    // externals: [
    //     'luxon'
    // ],
    output: {
        filename: '[name].js',
        library: {
            name: 'example-lib',
            type: 'umd'
        }
    }
};
```

Adding the dependency to the `externals` option in Webpack excludes the dependency from the bundle, which is what I want, but gives me the error

```
ReferenceError: __WEBPACK_EXTERNAL_MODULE_luxon__ is not defined
```

when running in a browser application that imports my library.

Comment: @RavgeetDhillon Unfortunately no, I ended up just bundling the dependency as described in the post

Answer (score 0):

use `self.importScripts("cdnurl/lodash.js")`

```
self._.find(xxx)
```

Comment: Code only answer are considered low-quality, please explain what your code is doing and how it addresses the question. Also format your answer property.